# Inline "details" element: problem with searching

Tags: html, css

```css
details, summary { display: inline; }
summary { cursor: pointer; user-select: none; }
summary::marker { content: ''; }
```

```html
<div>foo<details>
  <summary>*</summary>
  bar</details>
</div>
```

Why doesn't searching `foo*` work with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> on your keyboard and is there a way to make it searchable?

Another test:

```css
div, summary {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div>foo<div>*</div></div>
<div>foo<summary>*</summary></div>
```

Experiment with `textContent`: https://jsfiddle.net/0u2y1ozt/

Only the first `foo*` is searched. So it seems that `summary` is a special element when it comes to searching.

Comment: Please add more details about "searching". Who is searching and how?

Comment: @m4n0 Searching with Ctrl+F on your keyboard.

Comment: Because there is no string foo* on the page.

Comment: @Paulie_D But why? For example, if I have `<p>foo</p><p>bar</p>` and `p { display: inline; }`, then `foo bar` is searched correctly.

Comment: @jsv I had to delete my answer since it indeed looks like an exception. This could be a bug or a nice find from you. Only to be decided by the authors - https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interactive-elements.html#the-summary-element

Comment: @jsv I have opened the issue on Github: https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/6612

Comment: @m4n0 Thanks, I wasn't aware of this issue tracker :-)

Comment: I just tested it in Firefox and there is no such an issue. So it seems this is a Chrome bug. I will report it. I already have 2 confirmed Chrome bugs :-)

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1202113